# RemoteViews setOnClickPendingIntent not firing for Widget ListView

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a ListView Widget for Honeycomb and above.

I have a bar across the top with setOnClickPendingIntents in the onUpdate and they all work fine.

However in my ListViewAdapter in the RemoteViews getViewAt() function setOnClickPendingIntents never fires.

The strange thing is it was working fine in ICS, but stopped on my JellyBean devices.

My Code is as follows

```
@Override
public RemoteViews getViewAt(final int position) {
    final RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), layout);
            final PendingIntent home_intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(
            INTENT_ACTION_HOME), Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.row_item, home_intent);
}
```

This exact same intent fired in the onUpdate function of the widget works fine, just not when in the ListView Adapter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docs

public void setOnClickPendingIntent (int viewId, PendingIntent pendingIntent)

Equivalent to calling setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener) to launch the provided PendingIntent. **When setting the on-click action of items within collections (eg. ListView, StackView etc.), this method will not work.** Instead, use {@link RemoteViews#setPendingIntentTemplate(int, PendingIntent) in conjunction with RemoteViews#setOnClickFillInIntent(int, Intent).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. Set the setPendingIntentTemplate on the onUpdate function with a basic placeholder Intent and then set setOnClickFillInIntent to add the extras I want

Comment: @smith Instead of list item if i want the click event on the listView then how that can be done. Because if i use setOnClickPendingIntent on listView it cause problem in loading widget.

Comment: @AndroidDev, I also want to set clickListener on the whole listview.
Why would i set the same clicklisener on every item